# Bind Map in spring mvc

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc

I have a form in spring mvc 2 having command class "Class1"

I want to bind Class3 elements with an input field in this form. Below are my classes.

I am iterating/binding over Class2 elements in JSP other than map like this

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${class1.class2List}" varStatus="itemsRow">  
    <form:input path="class2List[${itemsRow.index}].anyElement2" />
    ..........
</c:forEach>
```

My Classes looks like

```
Class1
List<Class2> class2List;
String anyElement1;

Class2
Map<String, Class3> class2Map;
String anyElement2;

Class3
Map<String, Class3> class3Map;
String nameToGet;
String anyElement3;
```

How can I bind `anyElement3` inside `class3Map`. Is it possible?

**Edited for first Answer**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'class2List[0].class2Map[0]' of bean class [com.Class1]: Could not instantiate property type [com.Class3] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.Class3
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.newValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:641)
```

Comment: How do you set the class2List in your DAO and map it back to the object? Asking because i am having some problems

Comment: My DAO and class2List are different classes. I fill class2List object from JSP and then set the values of DAO object using these values.

Comment: You may have used ResultSetExtractor in your DAO can you look at this question for me and post an e.g. of how you used ResultSetExtractor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555163/parameterizedrowmapper-that-maps-object-list-to-object

Comment: Sorry I did not use ResultSetExtractor

Comment: Can you show me how you did row mapping to your list items in your class in the DAO?

Comment: You class 3 for e.g you have two string attributes and one Map so if you have to set class 3 you have to set a list of items for class3Map and two Strings. I am interested in how you may have used rowmapper to achieve this for class3Map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your `class2Map` has an entry with key, say, `mapkey`, try this:

```
<form:input path="class2List[${itemsRow.index}].class2Map['mapkey'].anyElement3" />
```

Comment: What exception? I have been doing that without any issue for a while now.

Comment: @imrantariq I had missed the `anyElement3` part. Edited my answer now.

Comment: Question modified. How can I bind anyElement3 inside class3Map. i.e. Class3 also contain HashMap

Comment: Just use a similar approach. Use `class2List[${itemsRow.index}].class2Map['key1'].class3Map['key2'].anyElement3`.

Comment: It creates exception. See question.

Comment: I think you have missed the single quotes. Make sure you use it exactly as I have shown. `class2Map['key']`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9593/discussion-between-imran-tariq-and-adarshr)

Answer (score 0):

org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'prsCDData[Forced][0]'

As in above exception how would you have property 'prsCDData[Forced][0]' in any object? . I think your path value is wrong.