# Binding a map of lists in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am not sure if this is a complex problem but as a starting person this seems a bit complex to me.
I have an object based on which i need to show some values on the UI and let user select some of them, i need to send data back to another controller when user click on the submit button.Here is the structure of my data object

```
public class PrsData{
private Map<String, List<PrsCDData>> prsCDData;
}

public class PrsCDData{
  private Map<String, Collection<ConfiguredDesignData>> configuredDesignData;
}

public ConfiguredDesignData{
  // simple fields
}
```

I have set the object in model before showing the view like

```
model.addAttribute("prsData", productData.getPrData());
```

In the form i have following settings

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="prsData" action="${addProductToCartAction}" >
<form:hidden path="prsCDData['${prsCDDataMap.key}']
  [${status.index}].configuredDesignData['${configuredDesignDataMap.key}']
  [${configuredDesignDataStatus.index}].code"/>

<form:hidden path="prsCDData['${prsCDDataMap.key}']
  [${status.index}].configuredDesignData['${configuredDesignDataMap.key}']
  [${configuredDesignDataStatus.index}].description"/>

</form:form>
```

This is what i have at `AddProductToCartController`

```
public String addToCart(@RequestParam("productCodePost") final String code,
@ModelAttribute("prsData") final PrsData prsData, final Model model,
@RequestParam(value = "qty", required = false, defaultValue = "1") final long qty)
```

On submitting the form i am getting following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'prsCDData[Forced][0]' 
of bean class [com.product.data.PrsData]: 
Cannot access indexed value of property referenced in indexed property path 'prsCDData[Forced][0]': returned null
```

It seems like its trying to access the values on this controller while i am trying to send value to that controller and trying to create same object with selected values

Can any one tell me where i am doing wrong and what i need to take care of

**Edit**

I did some more research and came to know that Spring do not support auto-populating list/map for custom objects and based on the answer i tried to change implementation like

```
public class PrsData{
    private Map<String, List<PrsCDData>> prsCDData;
    // lazy init
    public PrsData()
    {
           this.prsCDData = MapUtils.lazyMap(new HashMap<String, List<PrsCDData>>(),
                FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(PrsCDData.class));
        }
    }

    public class PrsCDData{
      private Map<String, Collection<ConfiguredDesignData>> configuredDesignData;
      public PrsCDData()
    {

       this.configuredDesignData = MapUtils.lazyMap(new HashMap<String,  
                                      List<ConfiguredDesignData>>(),
            FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(ConfiguredDesignData.class));

    }
    }
```

but i am getting following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: 
Invalid property 'prsCDData[Forced][0]' of bean class [com.data.PrsData]:
Property referenced in indexed property path 'prsCDData[Forced][0]' 
is neither an array nor a List nor a Set nor a Map; 
returned value was [com.data.PrsCDData@6043a24d]
```

i am not sure which thing i am doing wrong, it seems that either my JSTL expression is not right

Comment: Another thing to watch out for in this scenario is nested classes.  Making  `PrsCDData` a top level class could avoid this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Explanation :** if in you controller you have `@ModelAttribute("user") User user`, and you load a corresponding page that contains `<form:form commandName="user">`, an empty User is instantiated.

All its attributes are null, or empty in case of a List or a Map. Moreover, its empty lists/maps have been instantiated with an autogrowing implementation. What does it mean ? Let's say we have an empty autogrowing `List<Coconut> coconuts`. If I do `coconuts.get(someIndex).setDiameter(50)`, it will work instead of throwing an Exception, because the list auto grows and instantiate a coconut for the given index.
Thanks to this autogrowing, submitting a form with the below input will work like a charm :

```
<form:input path="coconuts[${someIndex}].diameter" />
```

---

**Now back to your problem :** Spring MVC autogrowing works quite well with a chain of objects, each containing a map/list ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943386/bind-map-in-spring-mvc/9974851#9974851)). But given your exception, it looks like Spring doesn't autogrow the possible objects contained by the autogrowed list/map. In `Map<String, List<PrsCDData>> prsCDData`, the `List<PrsCDData>` is a mere empty list with no autogrowing, thus leading to your Exception.

So the solution must use some kind of Apache Common's [LazyList](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/list/LazyList.html) or Spring's [AutoPopulatingList](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/util/AutoPopulatingList.html).
You must implement your own autogrowing map that instantiates a LazyList/AutoPopulatingList for a given index. Do it from scratch or using some kind of Apache Common's [LazyMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/LazyMap.html) / [MapUtils.lazyMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/MapUtils.html#lazyMap%28java.util.Map,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer%29) implementation (so far I have not found a Spring equivalent for LazyMap).

Example of solution, using Apache Commons Collections :

```
public class PrsData {

  private Map<String, List<PrsCDData>> prsCDData;

  public PrsData() {
      this.prsCDData = MapUtils.lazyMap(new HashMap<String,List<Object>>(), new Factory() {

          public Object create() {
              return LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList<PrsCDData>(), 
                             FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(PrsCDData.class));
          }

      });
  }

}
```

Comment: Nice explanation! Will try as per your suggestion and will update

Comment: trying first approach giving following exception `org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: 
Invalid property 'prsBTOData' of bean class [com.data.PrsData]: 
Could not instantiate property type [org.springframework.util.AutoPopulatingList] 
to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Could not instantiate Collection type: org.springframework.util.AutoPopulatingList`

Comment: can you explain second approach more as its not very clear to me.

Comment: I am not sure about your latest updated answer,as i changed my implementation to `AutoPopulatingList` and i got the exception as told my me.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi See my edited answer. This looks more complicated than I thought...

Comment: i tried with LazyMap but now getting a strange issue, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348491/unable-to-bind-data-using-spring-data-functionality.

Comment: Great answer!  Where did you pickup this information?

Comment: THANK. YOU. SRSLY.