# In JSP, Field Path Uses HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> (SpringMVC Form)

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Suppose my model field is a HashMap of Strings to ArrayList's of Strings.

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
```

For field binding, I need to point to an i-th item of the ArrayList of a specific key in my JSP. How do I do it? Will this double-bracket notation work? Assume that 'key' and 'index' are known JSTL variables in my JSP.

```
<form:checkbox path="map[${key}][${index}]" />
```

What I'm essentially doing is, for a field value, store its path e.g.

```
map['testkey'][4]
```

which would point to

```
map.get("testkey").get(4);
```

That doesn't work:

```
org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'map[TestKey][0]'
```

**NOTE** According to this ([Binding a map of lists in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339013/binding-a-map-of-lists-in-spring-mvc)), this will be a problem because sub-objects are **not** auto-growable, and I need to implement a LazyList or a growable list? An ArrayList by itself is growable for Spring MVC's forms, but when used as a sub-collection, it's not? Very tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by following the LazyList/LazySet implementation in the link above, 
[Binding a map of lists in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339013/binding-a-map-of-lists-in-spring-mvc)

From their example,

```
public class PrsData {

  private Map<String, List<PrsCDData>> prsCDData;

  public PrsData() {
      this.prsCDData = MapUtils.lazyMap(new HashMap<String,List<Object>>(), new Factory() {

          public Object create() {
              return LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList<PrsCDData>(), 
                             FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(PrsCDData.class));
          }

      });
  }

}
```

Once I had a data structure like that mapped to my JSP Path, the field binding magically started working and I could then make my path e.g. `map["key"][index]` in the JSP.

As they replied, SpringMVC auto-converts simple lists and maps to Lazy collections, but does **not** do it when the collection is a subobject.