# Join without mapping entities in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Am not that good yet with spring. Before now I thought its unprofessional to build an application with spring without using hibernate ORM. Until yesterday when I spent a full day trying to execute a "ManyToOne" mapping. Then I came across some threads where I got to know that u should only use hibernate with spring if only u need ORM in your application. That jdbc template will suffice should you not need ORM. Now my question is do I still need relational mapping to execute JOINS in SPRING using JDBC TEMPLATE(without using hibernate at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spring JdbcTemplate** allows you deal with native Java driver to work with databases, writing less code than using it directly. As you have guessed, it is a good option when the performance is more important than build a robust application using the "easy way" that brings you an ORM like Hibernate for example.

Answering your question, if you are talking about the Hibernate annotations like `@ManyToOne` or similar, the answer is no. Using `JdbcTemplate` you won't need them. However, you will need to specify in every query what are the required columns of every table and the columns of the related ones that you will want to get.

The following links give you some examples about how to deal with `JdbcTemplate` and `joins`:

- [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455220/spring-jdbc-rowmapper-usage-for-eager-fetches)
- [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555163/parameterizedrowmapper-that-maps-object-list-to-object)

More information about `JdbcTemplate` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc)